# installing Ubuntu operating system server 18.04 / networks connectivity settings problem

Tags: camera

When I am installing Ubuntu operating system server 18.04, I am facing a problem representing in networks connectivity settings because the text mode asks me to choose among three options ( not connected, ipv4, ipv6 ).

any helps guys about [image]this issue?! , I'm waiting :)

Comment: What does this have to do with a RaspberryPi? Or the "camera" tag?

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are confused with the states of the interface (not connected, ipv4, ipv6) but there is only one interface `enp1s0`. The menu says *"Select an interface to configure it or select Done to continue"*. So select the interface `enp1s0` and configure it to use ipv4 and/or ipv6.